# react native camera returns thumbnail image

Tags: react-native

I want to create a camera in react native. I want that the photo taken through the camera should get display in the form of thumbnails instead of full screen size. Can anyone please suggest me , how to do it from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `react-native-camera` or `Expo` as your `Camera` component provider library.

Taking a picture is similar in both. You'll need a ref to your `Camera` component.Then, you can use `cameraRef.takePictureAsync()` function to take a picture. This will return a promise for the temporary URL of the picture, which you can display using

`<Image source={{uri: pictureUri}} style={{width: desiredWidth, height: desiredHeight}} />`